# Can Homebrew be run on a MacBook too old to run Big Sur?

Tags: homebrew

I am wondering if it is possible to run Homebrew on an older MacBook. I know that the current version of Homebrew only supports Big Sur (if I am reading the Homebrew page correctly).

Is it possible to run an older version of Homebrew on an older mac OS such as Sierra or even older, or does the software become obsolete/unusable at some point?

Answer (score 4):

I'm running brew just fine on macOS 10.14, but it won't work correctly on Sierra. Bottles aren't built for 10.12 anymore, which means they'll start compiling themselves, which usually fails.

If you're running 10.6 to 10.12, I'd recommend using [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org). For Tiger or Leopard, you may be able to use [TigerBrew](https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew), however I have not tried this.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful! I'll keep Mojave in mind as "oldest OS which definitely works with brew". I'll also ask around about MacPorts or TigerBrew. Is it the current version of homebrew by chance? –

Comment: Macports does do tiger and leopard as well. However the further you go back the more issues there are. But work is still being done to improve the coverage eg getting more modern c++working